# Does ASP.NET Web-api support Odata resource path?

Tags: odata, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

As per OData Uri conventions http://www.odata.org/documentation/uri-conventions#FilterSystemQueryOption the following Uri is valid.
http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Category(1)/Products?$top=2&$orderby=name

However the ASP.NET Web-API does not seem to support this (at least out of the box). It gives an error to the effect that it cannot find a controller called Category(1).

How to make this work with Web-API or is there a work around?

Comment: This is especially strange since the docs seem to imply that this is supported: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-routing-conventions.  Perhaps support for this syntax has been added since this question was asked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why your question didn't garner attention when you asked it..but it's a real issue.  The WebAPI supports a good deal of the OData spec, but not all of it to my understanding. Although, I have yet to find a resource describing precisely what aspects work.  Out of the box the default routes support one layer of nesting, not the two like in your example.  So something like :

```
mystuff.com/Category/5?$top2&orderby=name
```

With that said, i think you could craft something like what you want.  I haven't compiled/tested all of this, so bear with me....   In `global.asax` setup a pair of routes like so:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(name          : "WithCategoryFilter", 
                    routeTemplate : "api/v1/{controller}({catID})/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults      : new { id = RouteParameter.Optional}        );

routes.MapHttpRoute(name          : "WithoutCatFilter", 
                    routeTemplate : "api/v1/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    defaults      : new { id = RouteParameter.Optional}        );
```

Notice the order I registered the routes--**put the category filter first**.  The corresponding controller for these routes would look something like : :

```
 public class ProductCategoryController : BaseAPIController {
     public IEnumerable<Product> Products(int catID, int id) {
         var result = new List<Product>();

         //do category filtering here...

          return result;
     }
 }
```

So the first route would allow application of a category filter (`catID`) and an optional ProductID (`id`).  When the categoryID & parenthesis are excluded the 2nd route would catch.   You need two routes because there isn't a great way to filter out the parenthesis automatically.

As a side note you may be interested in [another answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10658731/215068) that identifies some other route-gymnastics your probably going to encounter.

Comment: That's what I had tried earlier but didn't work. That is api/{controller}({resourceId})/{action} translates to api/Category(1)/products and an error is thrown with the message "No type was found that matches the controller named 'Category(1)'.

Comment: Look at the answer a little closer.  I tried the above and it worked for me.  You need a PAIR of routes.  One works when category is provided (and includes the parenthesis), one when it is not provided.  NOTICE that the order I registered the routes.  I suspect yours was the other way around.

Comment: Yes that was the case. I could get it to work after changing the order of routes. Thank you so much!