# How does ASP.NET Web.api handle two methods with names starting with GET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am looking at the following tutorial from Microsoft.  As per this tutorial,

> In the first example, "products" matches the controller named
>   ProductsController. The request is a GET request, so the framework
>   looks for a method on ProductsController whose name starts with
>   "Get...". Furthermore, the URI does not contain the optional {id}
>   segment, so the framework looks for a method with no parameters. The
>   ProductsController::GetAllProducts method meets all of these
>   requirements.

What happens if there are two methods like GetAllProducts() and GetSoldProducts()?  Both have no parameters.

[Your First Web API Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you're using the default routes the short answer is :  the method defined first (at the top) of your class will be called.  the other method is inaccessible.

> NOTE : the beta behaved as above for 'matching multiple methods' - the RC & Release version is a bit more OCD. It throws an error if there are multiple potential matches. This change removes the confusion of multiple ambiguous matches. At the same time, it reduces our ability to mix REST and RPC style interfaces in the same controller, relying on the order & overlapping routes.

Stealing liberally from [another post I wrote on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439738/how-does-a-method-in-mvc-webapi-map-to-an-http-verb/10471854#10471854):

**WebAPI Matching Semantic**

The matching semantic used by WebAPI is fairly simple.

1. It matches the name of the action with the verb (verb = get? look for method starting with "get")
2. if  a parameter is passed, the api seeks an action with a parameter

So in your code sample  a GET request without a parameter matches the `Get*( )` function without an parameters.  A Get containing and ID looks for a `Get***(int id)`.

**Examples**

While the matching semantic is simple, it creates some confusion for MVC developers (well at least this developer).  Lets look at some examples :

*Odd Names* - Your get method can be named anything, so long as it starts with "get".  So in the case of a widget controller you can name your functions `GetStrawberry()` and it  will still be matched.  Think of the matching as something like :   `methodname.StartsWith("Get")`

*Multiple Matching Methods* - What happens if you have two Get methods with no parameters?  `GetStrawberry()` and `GetOrange()`.   As best I can tell, the function defined first (top of the file) in your code wins ...strange.   This has the side effect of making some methods in your controller unreachable (at least with the default routes)....stranger.

**UPDATE**

@WinFXGuy - This was a bit long to put in a comment, but ...

Don't jump to conclusions!  I tried to answer the question you posed, but that's only half the story.  There is plenty you can do to change the default behavior.

**First**, WebAPI supports much of the [oData](http://www.odata.org/) spec.  If you bubble an `IQueryable` up to your controller, oData paramaters are automatically integrated with the query object.  It takes parameters like `$filter`, `$top`, and `$skip`.   So you in your case you can write one method and pass something like `$filter=sale_date neq null`.

Additionally, you can apply the `[ResultLimit]` attribute to prevent people asking for 15 billion records.

**Second** you can modify the routes.  The default routes aim towards a RESTful api, where you generally have 1 controller per entity.  You can change the routes and make it RPC style.

If you look at my linked post I explain how I kept the default route binding,  added 'sub folders' and also allowed additional method calls for scenarios where i needed `GetAllProducts()` and `GetSoldProducts()`.

Comment: I don't like what I am reading!  That kind of limits asp.net web api capabilites.

Comment: I found that it looks at the parameter names to resolve overloads.  So api/food?name=orange called GetFoodByName(string name), and api/food?category=fruit called GetFoodByCategory(string category).

Comment: @LeeGrissom - good tip, I can't say I've noticed that.  Between the beta and the RC, however, the binding code seems to have changed - specifically an error is thrown for the scenario I described in *Multiple Matching Methods*.  I'm sure there are other changes too.  I've been meaning to update this post, but need to circle back and look at the new binding semantics in more depth.

Answer (score 12):

There are two possible solutions to this specific problem:

1. Alter MapHttpRoute calls to require specifying the name of the action. (I'm using Self-hosting syntax):

   ```
       config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               "API Route 1",
               "api/{controller}/{action}");

       config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               "API Route 2",
               "api/{action}",
               new { controller = "products" });
   ```

   So your http client would call:

   `api/products/GetAllProducts` OR `api/GetAllProducts`
   `api/products/GetSoldProducts` OR `api/GetSoldProducts`

   See:
   http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api
2. Place each method in a separate controller (ProductsController, SoldProductsController).  So you would call `api/products` and `api/soldproducts` to get your results.

---

Related topic... in the situation where you have a multiple Get actions that have a single primitive argument of the same type, ASP.NET Web API will look at the name of the argument to resolve which overloaded action to call.

For example, if you have two actions:

```
GetProductByName(string name) 
GetProductByCategory(string category)
```

your http client can call

```
api/products?name=hammer 
api/products?category=toys
```

and the routing engine will call the correct action.

Answer (score 4):

Adding an answer to reflect that the latest version of Web API supports `[Route]` attribute natively

```
[Route("api/products")]
public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts(){}

[Route("api/products/sold")]
public IEnumerable<Product> GetSoldProducts(){}
```

Comment: This to me is the best solution