# Create a RESTful service with 3 similar Get methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I want to create a REStful web service.

This service returns "Meetings" for a certain

**day**, **week** or **months**.

I would create 3 Get methods which takes date values determined by the API user.

```
GetMeetingsByDay(currentDate)
GetMeetingsByWeek(startDate,endDate)
GetMeetingsByMonth(startDate,endDate)
```

Having 3 Get methods I could not access the API anymore just via http-method type 'GET' like:

```
// GET: api/meetings/date
```

because there will be multiple GET...

I could merge the ByWeek and ByMonth methods and do this instead:

```
GetMeetings(startDate,endDate);
```

How would you make this service RESTful?

Comment: You can specify a route, seee http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't think of it in terms of the method names - I'd think of it in terms of the URLs to start with:

```
/api/meetings?date=...
/api/meetings?startDate=...&endDate=...
```

Think of it as a collection of meetings, and the query parameters are just that - *query* parameters. I would expect any value after the `meetings` element in the URL to be a meeting ID - for example, your `GetMeetings` method might return a meeting with an ID of `foobar` which I'd then expect to be able to fetch later with

```
/api/meetings/foobar
```

That suggests to me that you shouldn't have `date` as part of the URL path at all.

In terms of implementation, I don't know enough about WebAPI routing to know whether you could implement that with two methods of:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/meetings")]
public ... GetMeetings([FromUri] DateTime startDate, [FromUri] DateTime endDate)

[HttpGet]
[Route("api/meetings")]
public ... GetMeetings([FromUri] DateTime date)
```

... or whether you need to a single method with optional parameters:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/meetings")]
public ... GetMeetings(
    [FromUri] DateTime? date = null,
    [FromUri] DateTime? startDate = null,
    [FromUri] DateTime? endDate = null)
```

In the latter case you'd need to then validate that the set of arguments provided was valid.

(As noted in comments, you may not need the `Route` here at all.)

Comment: But the Route Attribute is only needed afair -please correct me - when I do not name my methods just GET? Just the the HTTP Verb.

Comment: @Elisa: Sorry, I can't parse your comment. If you find it works without the `Route` attribute, that's great - but I don't think it really affects the answer much.

Comment: there will be no GetMeetings() or GetMeetings(id) because I fetch only via date-/range

Comment: @Elisa: So don't implement those yet - although I'd *encourage* you to implement `GetMeeting(id)` just on general principle. Again, I don't see how that really affects the answer, in terms of what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: another alternative would be: public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] MeetingsRequest request) a complex object.

Comment: @Elisa: Sure, that would work. But definitely think about the URL structure before the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

> Web API 2 supports a new type of routing, called attribute routing.

This is the scenario where you need to use attribute routing.

eg:

```
 [Route("customers/{customerId}/orders")]
 public IEnumerable<Order> GetOrdersByCustomer(int customerId) { ... }
```

> One advantage of convention-based routing is that templates are
>   defined in a single place, and the routing rules are applied
>   consistently across all controllers. Unfortunately, convention-based
>   routing makes it hard to support certain URI patterns that are common
>   in RESTful APIs.

Read more here :

- [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)
- [Create a REST API with Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/create-a-rest-api-with-attribute-routing)

*From a previous good answer ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11146587/1155650)):*

If you have a multiple `Get` actions that have a single primitive argument of the same type, ASP.NET Web API will look at the name of the argument to resolve which overloaded action to call.

For example, if you have two actions:

```
GetProductByName(string name) 
GetProductByCategory(string category)
```

your http client can call as :

```
api/products?name=hammer 
api/products?category=toys
```

and the routing engine will call the correct action.

The SO question, [How does ASP.NET Web.api handle two methods with names starting with GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658640/how-does-asp-net-web-api-handle-two-methods-with-names-starting-with-get) can give you some more knowledge as it had been well answered.

**EDIT :**

> I could merge the ByWeek and ByMonth methods and do this instead:
>
> `GetMeetings(startDate,endDate);`

Definitely I would encourage this if you don't have any specific logic going into the `GetMeetingsbyWeek` and `GetMeetingsbyMonth`, like it merely fetches a list from database between the specified date range.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Web API routing - http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

Otherwise, you could use just a querystring - like `api/meetings/date?currentDate=x&startDate=x&endDate=x`

Answer (score 0):

For creating a `WebApi` `Controller` with multiple `GET` requests, You need to specify the route as follows:

```
routeTemplate:api/{Controller}/{action}/{param}
```

This should solve your problem.