# C# MVC HttpGet add parameters to route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In my controller I have action like this:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ManageOPIdentifierController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public OPIdentifiersVM Get(int pageSize, int pageNumber)
        {
```

How to add parameters pageSize and pageNumber to HttpGet? Because now when I have second method Get without parameters I get error because there are two routes with the same definition.
How should looks the first HttpGet route?

```
[HttpGet("[action]/{pageSize}&{pageNumber}")]
```

Code above doesn't work

Edit:
My question has been misunderstood.
I have two methods Get:

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public OPIdentifiersVM Get(int pageSize, int pageNumber)
```

and

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public List<OPIdentifierVM> Get()
```

There is no problem to read values from parameters pageSize and pageNumber. The problem is that I have two methods with the same Http("[action]"). And I get error:

```
AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches: 
ManageUuidWeb.Controllers.ManageOPIdentifierController.Get (OneProjectIdentifier.Web)
ManageUuidWeb.Controllers.ManageOPIdentifierController.Get (OneProjectIdentifier.Web)
```

If I good understood the comment I have to change name one of the method. But I want to know if it is possible to have two methods with the same name but with different parameters?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658640/how-does-asp-net-web-api-handle-two-methods-with-names-starting-with-get. You should also change remove the & with / in the route

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public OPIdentifiersVM Get([FromUri] int pageSize, [FromUri] int pageNumber)
```

(or `[FromRoute]` if you are using asp.net core) then it will be accessed by

```
http://localhost/api/ManageOPIdentifier/Get/10/1
```

or use query parameters for that (it would be better solution)

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public OPIdentifiersVM Get([FromQuery] int pageSize, [FromQuery] int pageNumber)
```

then

```
http://localhost/api/ManageOPIdentifier/Get?pageSize=10&pageNumber=1
```

also you can use simple `[HttpGet]` when your action name equals to http verb method name

Answer (score 0):

Answer: **Yes**, you can use two methods with the same name in C# as long as they have different parameters signatures.

But...

...in the world of **Attribute Routing**, they **cannot** share the same name if you use `[action]` in your routing template, which maps the URL path directly to the method name as its endpoint. **Both your Controller Methods **share the same name** so both map to the same routes or URL and conflict.**

Your Attribute `[action]` route attributes both map to `Get`, the **action method name**. So both would map to a URL, like: **https://example.com/get** and conflict.

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public OPIdentifiersVM Get (int pageSize, int pageNumber)
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public List<OPIdentifierVM> Get()

// To the Routing Middleware, they are interpreted as...

[HttpGet("[action]")]
public Get ()
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public Get ()

// This becomes two conflicting URLS as:
// https://example.com/get
// https://example.com/get
```

To fix it just change your method name to something new. Or, you can keep the name but change the Attribute route value to something like:

```
[HttpGet("route1")]
public OPIdentifiersVM Get (int pageSize, int pageNumber)

[HttpGet("route2")]
public List<OPIdentifierVM> Get ()


// This becomes two new URLS as:
// https://example.com/route1
// https://example.com/route2
```